# Date and Time Formatting error

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

**I'm having the date  "2016-08-05 14:46:53 +05:30" and the
date and time format which i have used is "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss +05:30"**
the problem is that when i'm parsing this date i get the output **"Tue Jan 05 14:46:53 GMT+05:30 2016"** i don't get what is the problem.
The code which i'm using is posted below.

```
public class DateFormater {
private static String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss +05:30";
private static String TAG = DateFormater.class.getSimpleName();
public static Date getDate(String s) {
    //Input s = 2016-08-05 14:46:53 +05:30
    Date date = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        date=dateFormat.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
public static String getCurrentDateString(Date date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat=SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    Log.i(TAG, "getCurrentDateString: "+dateFormat.format(date));
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
public static String getCurrentTimeString(Date date) {
    DateFormat dateFormat=SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    return dateFormat.format(date);//Tue Jan 05 14:46:53 GMT+05:30 2016
}}
```

Comment: `DD` isn't the token you're looking for, use `dd`.

Comment: Got it buddy .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your date format.

```
public class DateFormater {
    private static String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +05:30";
    private static String TAG = DateFormater.class.getSimpleName();

    public static Date getDate(String s) {
        // Input s = 2016-08-05 14:46:53 +05:30
        Date date = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            date = dateFormat.parse(s);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }

    public static String getCurrentDateString(Date date) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat
                .getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public static String getCurrentTimeString(Date date) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat
                .getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        return dateFormat.format(date);// Tue Jan 05 14:46:53 GMT+05:30 2016
    }       
}
```